# CSS HTML - adding an accordion bar across list items that are floated left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not even sure this is even possible or if I have to totally redo the layout of this thing:

[image]

I'm using a flexslider (in carousel mode) inside a fancybox. The three columns you see are list elements floating left (flexslider does that).

Is it possible to implement this accordion bar that goes across these floated list items while displaying only three blocks in each slide?

**Edit:**

I've got this far now.

[image]

However, this is not the initial request since the accordion label repeats in all columns. This is what the code looks like inside each list item for each column so far (I can't reveal too much code in here):

```
<div class="column">
    <!-- stuff at the top of the column that don't matter -->
    <hr />
            <!-- this below is where I'm trying to add the accordion -->
    <ul class="feature-checks">
        <li>Pool view</li>
        <li>395-397 sqft/37 sqm</li>
        <li><i class="arrow"></i> Beds and Bedding</li>
        <li>Midget-Sized Bed</li>
        <li>12" x 12" blankie</li>
        <li>Giant Fluffy Pillow</li>
        <li><i class="arrow"></i> Rooms Features</li>
        <li>50 lbs. Alarm Clock</li>
        <li>1970s TV</li>   
        <li><i class="arrow"></i> Bath and Bathroom Features</li>
        <li>Super Soaker</li>
        <li>500 HP Toilet</li>                                          
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit**

Okay, here is a codepen: http://cdpn.io/csgKz

Comment: So.. what have you tried..? where is the relevant code..? can you atleast provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Agreed with @TJ, just posting the HTML which is the structure won't help, we also need the CSS, which is the design and JS

Comment: @TJ hey I edited the post. I can't do a jsfiddle unfortunately because I would be revealing way too much stuff, but just take the code above and wrap it with <li></li> with float: left on the <li> items and the screenshot I have is about what you'll get.

Comment: @Colourity I posted the codepen link to it.

Comment: @TJ I posted a codepen.